# Use MacBook as Mysql Local Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, macos

I have a MacBook and I am currently working on a web-app for our school. I am using PHP, MySQL, and Apache, all provided through the XAMMP stack.

When testing the website via `localhost` it works fine. Now, some of my teachers wanted to try out the web-app via their phones. Can I configure my MacBook to work like some sort of a 'local server' (e.g. probably through the internal network) to which other devices on the same internal network can connect via their phone browsers?

Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt the network would be open like that, can you access the internet from the network?

Comment: Could try [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I think not. If there is an internet connection in the place, then the solution is clear: upload my php files to a live server online, register it to a url, and then just access the url in the phones right? But actually internet is not an option in my project since they wanted to put it in a local server. So I was thinking if I could let my macbook function as a server, that would help. I think this is possible in windows, but I'm not sure on mac

Comment: It's not about it functioning as a server, it will/is doing that already.. it's about the network setup, any network admin worth their salt will vlan/nat everything so 192.168.0.0/24 is not the same as at home. You would need to talk to them so they can allocate you a static IP so others/phones can access your server/laptop.

Comment: If you both are on the same network then yes, Do an `ifconfig` on your mac terminal and give them your local IP address and also in your apache configuration allow external IPs. If the first case doesn't meet and you are not on the same network you need to have a static valid ip Address. I hope it helps

Comment: @PooyaRaki Thanks for the heads up! It helps

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes thank you! The static IP is helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand in using a Website, the client itself doesn't need to contact the database server. The web server is the one who communicate with database server and send/serve html pages to the client.

Phpmyadmin is a website not a database itself. So you simply need to allow access to your web server,you can use your laptop as web server. Test directly using your laptop as a web server, open the website instead using localhost change it to your laptop ip address. If it's not working then tell us the error so we can help you from there.